# Created a new iOS App. Cannot update old one. Will Apple accept an update that just tells users to download the new one?

Tags: iphone, ios

The app has a different bundle identifier and the old app is not enable for push notifications.  We want to update the old app with one screen and a button that sends the users to the app store to download the new app.  Will Apple even approve that?  Any ideas on a better way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use the old bundle identifier?

Answer (score 0):

If it has a different bundle id it's probably possible. I've seen many apps doing this. For example free apps! They seduce the users with new features to buy the full app. So it wont be a problem to connect both apps via link to itunes. If you use Push N be sure to set up all correctly. My idea is to set the old one to a free app and connect them. And why dont you make the budles the same? Like a normal update?

Answer (score 0):

We had to do something similar when an App we developed needed to change from our account to our customer's account (to comply with their internal brand standards). We updated the old app to say "We've Moved." and had a link to the itms: for the new version. We did let the user dismiss the notice and keep using the old version, though.

I'm sure they'll approve it if you let the user put off upgrading. Maybe not if you force them to upgrade as you suggested in your question.